# How to configure mailx to support Gmail?

Tags: shell-script, mailx

How can I set up `mailx` to send messages to my Gmail account? What I do now is run the command:

```
mail -s "hello kid" mymail@gmail.com
```

It freezes and does nothing. I tried some variations, but all of them just froze dead in my terminal. Is there anything I need to configure in `mailx` before actually using `mail`?

There were different options found on the Internet, like making a `.mailrc` and other config files, but I got nowhere. Can someone provide me with more information on the subject?

Comment: I suspect it's exactly as complex as the guides you found told you it was. You the user think "just send email to gMail", but behind the scenes you have to deal with encryption, authentication, remote server addresses, protocol choices... All of that is exposed to you when you insist on using an old-school client like `mailx`. If you want a console mail program but would rather not pay attention to so many details, surely `alpine` or `mutt` would be easier to make work with gMail?

Comment: I used alpine for some time and liked it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `mail -s "hello kid" mymail@gmail.com` is waiting for you to type the mail message and then control-d.  After you do that the message will be sent.  If you just want a quick test, do:

```
echo `date` this is a test | mail mymail@gmail.com
```

and the message will be sent immediately.

Comment: thanks, it works now. And I was wondering why was it hanging)

Answer (score 2):

You can also redirect a file to mail.
Useful when sending mail via `cron`

`mail -s "Logs" mymail@gmail.com < /var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up two factor auth within security settings in google account and get a 16 digit app password. Create a mailrc file

```
nano ~/.mailrc
```

and paste

```
account gmail {
    set smtp-use-starttls
    set ssl-verify=ignore
    set smtp-auth=login
    set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587
    set from="email@address(Name)"
    set smtp-auth-user=email@address
    set smtp-auth-password=16 digit app password
}
```

then send you message

```
echo -e "Message body" | mailx -s "Subject" receiver@email
```